# AJAX - How to make Asynchronous request one by one without freeze browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

i have a textarea like below:

```
<textarea name="mailist" id="mailist" placeholder="email@domain.com"></textarea>
```

I want to make a request from the mailist, and send the data (email-per-line) to some URL using "split" and "foreach" . And it success.

But the problem is, when i click the submit button, the all request sent at the same time. How can i make it to:

- Send the request after the end of the other
- Make a request Asynchronously
- Not freeze the browser

Comment: Using `.success` handler..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a `promise`. Every `$.ajax` function in jQuery returns a `promise`. You can read the [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to get more details. The gist is, the returned promise exposes a function called `then`, which can be used to chain requests one after the other, in the manner you desire.

Consider an ajax request of this sort

```
var request = $.ajax({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'www.google.com'
});
```

Since it runs asynchronously, you need to register handlers to let you know when the request is completed successfully, or failed, like so

```
request.then(
    function successHandler(response) {
        /* The first function will be called if the request is successful */
    },
    function failureHandler(response) {
       /* The second function will be called if the request fails */
    }
);
```

Using this pattern, you could wait for a request to either succeed or fail, before proceeding to the next one.

**Leaving the earlier code section intact**

You need to implement a queue of sorts. Most browsers have a sane limit of about 2-5 simultaneous requests. An example would be

```js
var emailAddresses = [/* a list email addresses */];
var MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_REQUESTS = 4;
var CURRENT_REQUESTS = [];

function runRequests(emailAddresses, max, running) {
  while(running.length < max) {
    running.push(createRequest(emailAddress.pop(), running));
  }
  return emailAddresses.length;
}

function createRequest(emailAddress, running) {
  var request = /* Creates requests in some manner */;
  request
    .then(
      function() {
        /* Remove this request from the list of running requests */
        var indexOfRequest = running.indexOf(request);
        running.splice(indexOfRequest, 1);
      },
      function() {
        /* For extra points, add this to a retry queue */
      }
    );
  
  return request;
}

/* Usage */
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var remaining = runRequests(emailAddresses, MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_REQUESTS, CURRENT_REQUESTS);
  if (remaining === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: I feel that OP isn't going to understand this based on the questions he is asking. His problem is not the bottleneck of multiple requests.

Comment: @A1rPun Yes, i just want to make Asynchronous request one by one when i click the submit button

Comment: @A1rPun you make a valid point. I should probably explain the `then` sections

Comment: @JibiAbraham  It should be `running.push(createRequest(emailAddresses.pop(), running));`